# Proof complement of sets

Tags: probability

> $P(A \cap  B) \geq 1- P(A^c) - P(B^c)$

I want to prove this. My attempt:

$P(A \cap  B) \geq 1- P(A^c) - P(B^c) \iff P(A \cap  B) \geq P(A) - P(B^c) \iff P(A \cap B) + P(B^c) \geq P(A)$

So I know that visually, $A$ is subsumed by $[(A \cap B )\cup B^c]$ because that expression spans the whole of $A$. But mathematically, using probabilities, how would I finish my proof here?

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$
P(A\cap B)=1-P(A^c\cup B^c)
$$
and
$$
P(A^c\cup B^c)\le P(A^c)+P(B^c).
$$
Hence,
$$
P(A\cap B)=1-P(A^c\cup B^c)\ge1-(P(A^c)+P(B^c))=1-P(A^c)-P(B^c).
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that $1\geq P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. 
Hence
$$1- P(A^c) - P(B^c)=1-(1-P(A))-(1-P(B))=P(A)+P(B)-1\leq P(A\cap B).$$

Answer (score 0):

If we split $B^c$ into a union of two disjoint sets (inside $A$ and outside $A$), we get
$\ldots \iff P(A \cap B) + P(B^c) \geq P(A) \iff P(A \cap B) + \left( P(B^c\cap A) + P((A\cup B)^c) \right) \geq P(A)$.

Then we re-group the parts of the sum:

$\ldots \iff \left( P(A \cap B) +  P(B^c\cap A) \right) + P((A\cup B)^c) \geq P(A) \iff P(A) + P((A\cup B)^c) \geq P(A)$

This concludes the proof because $P((A\cup B)^c) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is fine. You could finish by stating that:

$$\Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(B^c)=\Pr((A\cap B)\cup B^c)\geq\Pr(A)$$ Here $=$ because the sets $A\cap B$ and $B^c$ are disjoint and $\geq$ because set $A$ is a subset of set $(A\cap B)\cup B^c$.

In general if $U\subseteq V$ then $U=V\cup (U-V)$ (a disjoint union) so that: $$\Pr(U)=\Pr(V\cup (U-V)=\Pr(V)+\Pr(U-V)\geq\Pr(V)$$